# PowerShell -or issue with Get-Smbshare

Tags: windows, powershell

When i run the following PowerShell (v5) code, the exclusions (C$, ADMIN$, IPC$ are not happening).

```
$shares = Get-SmbShare | where {$_.Name -ne "IPC$" -or $_.name -ne "C$" -or $_.name -ne "ADMIN$"}
$shares
```

the output is

```
Name      ScopeName Path           Description  
----      --------- ----           -----------  
ADMIN$    *         C:\WINDOWS     Remote Admin 
C$        *         C:\            Default share
IPC$      *                        Remote IPC   
share2    *         C:\Temp\share2              
Sharetest *         C:\Temp\Share
```

I can remedy the issue with this:

```
$shares = Get-SmbShare | where {$_.Name -ne "IPC$"} | where {$_.name -ne "C$"} | where {$_.name -ne "ADMIN$"}
$shares
```

which gives the desired output of:

```
Name      ScopeName Path           Description
----      --------- ----           -----------
share2    *         C:\Temp\share2            
Sharetest *         C:\Temp\Share
```

I'm looing for something that could handle a bigger exclusion list more elegantly and efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an often-confused issue when using `-and` and `-or`, or their equivalent in other programming and/or scripting languages.

If you are looking to completely ***exclude*** a set of names, you want the match to use `-and` - If the name is not C$ AND the name is not IPC$ AND the name is not ADMIN$, then include it in the list. Try

```
$shares = Get-SmbShare | where {$_.Name -ne "IPC$" -and $_.name -ne "C$" -and $_.name -ne "ADMIN$"}
$shares
```

`-or` doesn’t work because the share name `C$` returns `$true` for the match `$_.Name -ne "IPC$"`, and `$true -or` «anything» is `$true`.

A possibly “cleaner” way of handling this might be to create an array of exclusions, and then use `-notin` to check the list of objects to be selected from:

```
$Exclusions = "C$", "ADMIN$", "IPC$"
$Shares = Get-SMBShare | Where-Object {$_.Name -notin $Exclusions}
```

With this, instead of making an increasingly long and unwieldly string of comparisons joined with `-and` or `-or`, you would just add the specific exclusion to the list of exclusions, and leave the rest of the code the same.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would use a regular expression:

```
$shares = Get-SmbShare | Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch '^(?:IPC|C|ADMIN)\$$'}
$shares
```

Regex details

```
^              # Assert position at the beginning of the string
(?:            # Match the regular expression below
               # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      IPC      # Match the characters “IPC” literally
   |           # Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      C        # Match the character “C” literally
   |           # Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      ADMIN    # Match the characters “ADMIN” literally
)
\$             # Match the character “$” literally
$              # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

As I'm using `-notmatch` all shares named `IPC$`, `C$` and `ADMIN$` will be filtered out of the result

Comment: Why a regex `-notmatch` instead of the `-notin` that I proposed? Are there efficiency issues that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin No, your answer is excellent and I just wanted to provide another way using regex. With that few exclusions there won't be any difference in execution time, but when the array with exclusions gets very long, I would suspect regex will be faster

Comment: I think that might depend on how similar the various excluded names are. The next time we have to do a cleanup on our Active Directory, I might have an excuse to do this comparison...